# Displaying a list of items in a grid Tapestry-error

Tags: tapestry

I want to display a list of items in a grid and i got this error:
Failure parsing template classpath:com/mycompany/licenta/pages/ShowAll.tml: The  element has been deprecated in Tapestry 5.3 in favour of 'tapestry:parameter' namespace.
My .tml page is:

```html
<html t:type="layout" title="Show All"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

   <head>
   <title>Lista Hoteluri</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <t:grid t:source="hotelSource" rowsPerPage="5"
row="hotel">
<t:parameter name="numeHotelCell">
<t:pagelink t:page="details" t:context="hotel.id">
${hotel.numeHotel}
</t:pagelink>
</t:parameter>
</t:grid>
   

<br/>
      <a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="Index">
      Back to the Start Page</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

I've searched on the Internet about this problem but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the **t:parameter** element has been deprecated. Technically, it was actually *removed* in Tapestry 5.3. In any case, all you need to do is use the newer, more concise **p:** syntax (the "parameter" XML namespace) instead:

```
<p:numeHotelCell>
    <t:pagelink t:page="details" t:context="hotel.id">
        ${hotel.numeHotel}
    </t:pagelink>
</p:numeHotelCell>
```

This is mentioned briefly here: https://tapestry.apache.org/component-templates.html

This "parameter" namespace, using the "p:" prefix here, is already defined at the top of your template. (Technically you could declare a prefix other than "p:", but that would be unconventional.)